# Unable to show result due to TypeError: Result of expression 'parentElement' [null] is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to send my result from one html page to another by using localStorage. However when I tried to run my phonegap, an error (file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 41 : TypeError: Result of expression 'parentElement' [null] is not an object.) keeps appearing which cause my result to be appear as NULL and I'm unable to get it solve regardless of the various methods I try. Will be thankful if someone could help me solve this issue!

```js
var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  // Bind Event Listeners
  //
  // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
  // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
  bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },
  // deviceready Event Handler
  //
  // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
  // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  },
  // Update DOM on a Received Event
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
  }
};

app.initialize();
```

```html
// calculate.html

<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculatedBMI() {
    var BMI = calculate(parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("height")), parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("weight")); localStorage.setItem("BMI", BMI));
    document.BMIform.submit();
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>


  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="index.html" onclick="javascript:home()" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right">Home</a>
      <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="navbar">
      <p>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter your height and weight. The system will calculator your BMI: </i>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form name="BMIform" id="BMIform">
        <label for="height">Height</label>
        <input type="text" name="height" id="height" placeholder="Enter your height in metres!">

        <label for="weight">Weight</label>
        <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="Enter your weight in KG!">

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Gender</legend>

          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" checked>

          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female">
        </fieldset>

        <label for="dreamweight">Dream Weight</label>
        <input type="text" name="dreamweight" id="dreamweight" placeholder="Enter your dream weight in KG!">

        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter your age!">

        <label for="exercisefrequency">Exercise Frequency</label>
        <select name="exercisefrequency" id="exercisefrequency">
          <option value="1">Hardly Exercise</option>
          <option value="2">Exercise 1 to 3 times a week</option>
          <option value="3">Exercise 3 to 5 times a week</option>
          <option value="4">Exercise 5 to 7 times a week</option>
          <option value="5">Intensive Exercise more than 7 times a week</option>
        </select>

        <a href="result.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" onclick="javascript:result()">Calculate</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>



//result.html

<script type="text/javascript">
  var BMI = localStorage.getItem("BMI");
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="index.html" onclick="javascript:home()" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right">Home</a>
      <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="navbar">
      <p>
        <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your Results</b>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      You are :
      <script>
        document.write(totalclassification)
      </script>
      <br>
      <br>BMI:
      <script>
        document.write(BMI)
      </script>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're calling `app.receivedEvent('deviceready')`, which means that `deviceready` will be the value of the variable `id`. Thus `parentElement` will be the result of `document.getElementById('deviceready')`. Is this intentional? You do not appear to have such an element?

Comment: You also have a `document.write(totalclassification)` where `totalclassification` isn't defined in your code.

Comment: There are other errors as well in the JS console: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
"height")), parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("weight"));` and `ReferenceError: totalclassification is not defined`.

Comment: @DavidHedlund , No it wasn't. Because this is a school work & I'm changing the codes according to my project. The part on "deviceready" isn't suppose to appear in my project as an element. I forgot to delete the totalclassification; I have yet to define that.

Comment: @Kenney I have changed it accordingly, thank you!

Comment: Well, the error you're seeing is still due to the fact that you're doing `document.getElementById('deviceready')` and then proceeding to run `querySelector` on a null reference. If there are any other problems with your code, you will need to specify.